# Java stream map-if-or-else with predicate and alternative value

Tags: java, java-stream, mapping, predicate

Do Java streams have a convenient way to map based upon a predicate, but if the predicate is not met to map to some other value?

Let's say I have `Stream.of("2021", "", "2023")`. I want to map that to `Stream.of(Optional.of(Year.of(2021)), Optional.empty(), Optional.of(Year.of(2023)))`. Here's one way I could do that:

```java
Stream<String> yearStrings = Stream.of("2021", "", "2023");
Stream<Optional<Year>> yearsFound = yearStrings.map(yearString ->
    !yearString.isEmpty() ? Year.parse(yearString) : null)
        .map(Optional::ofNullable);
```

But here is what I would like to do, using a hypothetical filter-map:

```java
Stream<String> yearStrings = Stream.of("2021", "", "2023");
Stream<Optional<Year>> yearsFound = yearStrings.mapIfOrElse(not(String::isEmpty),
    Year::parse, null).map(Optional::ofNullable);
```

Of course I can write my own `mapIfOrElse(Predicate<>, Function<>, T)` function to use with `Stream.map()`, but I wanted to check if there is something similar in Java's existing arsenal that I've missed.

Comment: afaik there is nothing like that, though for this situation might be simpler just to wrap the parse method in your own that does the check, and returns null if the String is empty, which is what you're doing in the first example, just method references look nicer for longer logic imo.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a very much better way of doing it than you have it - it might be nicer if you extracted it to a method, but that's really it.

Another way might be to construct Optionals from all values, and then use `Optional.filter` to map empty values to empty optionals:

```
yearStreams.map(Optional::of)
           .map(opt -> opt.filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty)));
```

Is this *better*? Probably not.

Yet another way would be to make use of something like [Guava's `Strings.emptyToNull`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#emptyToNull(java.lang.String)) (other libraries are available), which turns your empty strings into null first; and then use `Optional.ofNullable` to turn non-nulls and nulls into non-empty and empty `Optional`s, respectively:

```
yearStreams.map(Strings::emptyToNull)
           .map(Optional::ofNullable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use `filter` to validate and then only `map`

```
Stream<Year> yearsFound = yearStrings.filter(yearString->!yearString.isEmpty()).map(Year::parse)
```

Comment: The requirement in the question was not to filter them out, instead map them to null.

Answer (score 0):

It's hardly possible to combine all these actions smoothly in well-readable way within a single stream operation.

Here's a weird method-chaining with Java 16 [`mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)):

```
Stream<Optional<Year>> yearsFound = yearStrings
    .mapMulti((yearString, consumer) -> 
        Optional.of(yearString).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).map(Year::parse)
                .ifPresentOrElse(year -> consumer.accept(Optional.of(year)),
                    () -> consumer.accept(Optional.empty()))
    );
```